# Sort two-dimensional array without touching second dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

**First, you may wonder:** Why do you need to have two dimensions, just create two one-dimensional arrays.
*Well, here is my task*: user types number of queries and then for each query he enters ID of the task, for ID = 0 I need to use first array ([][0]) and for ID = 1 second one, would be much prettier to do it without if statement (`if (ID == 0)...blablabla`).
Of course there is a way to do this with sorting algorithms (bubble, quick ...), but I'm kind of curios: Can it be done with `std::sort();` function?
Thanks.
P.s. Here is quick example to clarify:

I so sorry to give such a bad example I,m gonna edit it, first here goes data that I have

```
2 1   
14 5   
5 7   
3 45  `
```

so I need to sort It like this:

```
2 1   
3 5   
5 7   
14 45
```

so when queries are entered for example id=1 number=2 just output `array[2][1];`

Comment: It sounds like you need a multimap, not a 2d array.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you question(s). You want to know if you can sort it sort() function? Of course you can. Check this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Comment: [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) (with `int` key and `int` value) is almost certainly what you want to use here as it is inherently sorted by key and provides logarithmic complexity searching.

Comment: If Altainia's answer is not satisfying, why did you accept it ? Also, I don't see in your question the reason why you don't want a couple of unidimensional arrays.

Comment: Yeah I did it with two one-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the data as a structure of some kind

```
struct data{
  int id;
  int other_data;
  ...
};
```

To sort by ID only...

```
{
  std::vector<data> my_vec;
  //Populate my_vec
  std::sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), [](const data& d1, const data& d2){
    return d1.id < d2.id;
  });
}
```

Three benefits:

1. If you later need `other_data_2` to also stay ordered with `id`, it's trivial to add it
2. You can avoid using complicated multi-dimensional arrays
3. You can avoid using arrays (by using vectors)

Comment: Wouldn't this also sort the `other_data` in the data nodes ? In this code `id `and `other_data` will stay together, which is what the OP does not want.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I didn't see that in his example when I first looked at it. ...